# Output Stream NullPointerException

Tags: java, file-io, stream, output

I'm trying to get the string input from the user and store it in a file but an error comes out saying:
I don't know what the issue is, it doesn't pop up as an error until I actually run the code. I just want the input from the user stored in a file that is made

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BingoHelper.<init>(BingoHelper.java:53)
    at BINGO.main(BINGO.java:8)
```

Main Class Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class BINGO {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            JLabel bg = new JLabel();
            //JButton b = new JButton("Click to enter name");
            BingoHelper EnterFaze = new BingoHelper();
            EnterFaze.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            EnterFaze.setSize(500,500);
            EnterFaze.setVisible(true);
            EnterFaze.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            EnterFaze.setLayout(null);
            EnterFaze.add(bg);
        }
    }
```

Second Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BingoHelper extends JFrame implements WindowListener, ActionListener{
    JTextField text = new JTextField();

JLabel bg = new JLabel();

private JButton b; {
        b = new JButton("Click to enter name");
        }

JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();


public static String fn;
public static String sn;

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    //BingoHelper.fn;
    //BingoHelper.sn;
    fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first name?");
    sn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your second name(Optional)");
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " + fn + " " + sn + ".", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    text.setText("Welcome " + fn + " " + sn + ".");
    b.setVisible(false);
    text.setVisible(true);
    text.setBounds(140,0,220,20);
    text.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
} 

public BingoHelper() throws IOException{
    super("BINGO");
    add(text);
    text.setVisible(false);
    add(b);
    this.add(pnlButton);
    pnlButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    //pnlButton.add(b);+
    b.setVisible(true);
    b.setBounds(145,145,145,20);
    //b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
    b.addActionListener(this);
    b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    rootPane.setDefaultButton(b);
    File f = new File("test.txt");

    String nameToWrite = fn;
    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
    outStream.write(nameToWrite.getBytes());
    outStream.close();
}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    dispose();
    System.exit(0);

}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
```

}

Comment: Which is line 53?  Have you used the debugger to check the values of variables, etc. at that point?

Comment: Can you post the lines surrounding: `BingoHelper.java:53`?

Comment: Sorry: this is line 53
  outStream.write(nameToWrite.getBytes());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your helper code to the below to get what you are looking for.  The change I have done is,

1. Removed the code to write to file in the constructor.
2. Added a new method to write to file.
3. Invoked the new method from actionPerformed.

```
public class BingoHelper extends JFrame implements WindowListener, ActionListener {
    JTextField text = new JTextField();
    JLabel bg = new JLabel();
    private JButton b;
    {
        b = new JButton("Click to enter name");
    }
        JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
        public static String fn;
        public static String sn;
```

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // BingoHelper.fn;
    // BingoHelper.sn;
    fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first name?");
    sn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your second name(Optional)");
    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " + fn + " " + sn + ".", "",
    // JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    text.setText("Welcome " + fn + " " + sn + ".");
    b.setVisible(false);
    text.setVisible(true);
    text.setBounds(140, 0, 220, 20);
    text.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    writeToFile();
}

private void writeToFile() {
    File f = new File("test.txt");

    String nameToWrite = fn;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        outStream.write(nameToWrite.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != outStream) {
            try {
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}

public BingoHelper() throws IOException {
    super("BINGO");
    add(text);
    text.setVisible(false);
    add(b);
    this.add(pnlButton);
    pnlButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    // pnlButton.add(b);+
    b.setVisible(true);
    b.setBounds(145, 145, 145, 20);
    // b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
    b.addActionListener(this);
    b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    rootPane.setDefaultButton(b);
}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    dispose();
    System.exit(0);

}

public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
}

public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
}

public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
}

public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
}

public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
}

public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
}}

Comment: Thank you really much this worked! Thanks!
I've heard of the try and catch method, I just don't know what it does or what an exception even is :/ Can you comment the code to help me.. or even better provide a site that explains what Exceptions are and what the try and catch method does (for beginners).

Comment: This may be help you to understand exception handling. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/index.html

Comment: @JavaScrub: This is why you should be learning from a book. It will teach you what you need to know in a coherent order. That's going to be *much* more productive than trial and error, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, you are absolutely right no doubt! I'm probably going to take out a book tomorrow from class and just go on for now.
On the other side, I was watching tutorials that apparently went in the correct order from thenewboston channel but my teacher told us that midterm conferences are coming up so I needed to pick up my pace and start GUI, JFrame, ActionListeners, and just came across an idea to use FS for my program as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
String nameToWrite = fn;
...
outStream.write(nameToWrite.getBytes());
```

`fn` will only have a non-null value after `actionPerformed` has been called at least once. So when you call the constructor, `fn` is null, so `nameToWrite` is null, so `nameToWrite.getBytes()` throws a `NullPointerException`. What name did you *expect* to get at this point? Why are you writing to a file during a constructor? That seems a very odd thing to do. Shouldn't it be written in response to a user action?

(As an aside, don't use `getBytes()` without specifying a charset anyway - and prefer creating an `OutputStreamWriter` around the `OutputStream`, rather than performing the text to binary conversion yourself. And close the stream either with a finally block, or a try-with-resources statement.)

Comment: I'm a flop at Java so I'm just learning the "new parts" to me and exploring

I tried using the outputstream under the action performed but it won't let me throw IOException... I'm so dumb I should probably get a book >_< Still need help on how to fix XD

Comment: @JavaScrub: Trying to learn a language just by experimentation isn't a very productive approach. I would definitely get a book. As for fixing this issue - I think you need to take a step back and think about when you want to write out the file, and with what content.

Comment: I have a button which I use and that button pops up a in input box. I want the name entered in the Input Box to be saved into the File that I make. I tried writing the file from the actionlistener but apparently that throws no exceptions. I'm really stuck on how to get this to work :l

Comment: @JavaScrub: Well you need to work out what you want to do if it *does* throw an exception. For example, you could catch the exception within the action listener.

Answer (score 0):

You got a NullPointerException since fn was null. NullPointerException is so common in Java programming, you should look all variable in the line number which has thrown exception. For a better understanding on NullPointerException refer http://javapapers.com/core-java/nullpointerexception-null-bad-good-and-ugly/

Do you really want to write the file from the constructor?

Comment: Nope, I have a button which I use and that button pops up a in input box. I want the name entered in the Input Box to be saved into the File that I make. I tried writing the file from the actionlistener but apparently that throws no exceptions. I'm really stuck on how to get this to work :l